# Showing XSLT compilation error in IDE

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

We have many xslt files for our transformation. We defined the name space in the main xslt file as a variable and include it in all other xslt files.

In main xslt defined as bellow.

```
<xsl:variable name="namespaceV">http://Test.org/Tests/789</xsl:variable>
```

We use this in other xslt files as bellow.

```
<xsl:element name="Name" namespace="{$namespaceV}">
```

We don't have any issues in transformation but our IDE shows the compilation error as bellow.

**It is an error to refer to a variable or parameter that is not defined.**

Please suggest me how can I avoid this compilation error from IDE?

**Updated:**

We define the variable in the main xslt and use it in the child xslts files.

**Variable definition in main xslt.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">     
<xsl:variable name="namespaceV">http://Test.org/Tests/789</xsl:variable>
```

**The usage of this variable in the child xslt files.**

```
 <xsl:element name="Name" namespace="{$namespaceV}">
```

**Include the child xslt files in the mian xslt file.**

```
<xsl:include href="Uduppiddy/AMC/Student.xsl" />
```

Comment: Well which IDE exactly do you use?

Comment: I use RAD (IBM Rational Application Developer).

Comment: Where do you declare the variable and how do you include it in "all other XSLT files"?

Comment: I have a main xslt file to include all other xslt files. I declared variable in the main xslt and use it in all the other xslt files which are included in the main xslt file. If you check my question you may get some more idea.

Comment: I have **read** your question of course, that's not the problem. If you care about an answer, please tell us where exactly you declare this variable (as a top-level element, inside `xsl:template` or inside `xsl:for-each`?). Also, say whether you `xsl:include` or `xsl:import` the "other" stylesheets.

Comment: We used that common variable to define the name space. so in each XSLT when we create the new element we use that variable. ex: <xsl:element name="Name" namespace="{$namespaceV}">. I declared this variable in main xslt under the root element <xsl:stylesheet>. This variable declaration is the first line inside the <xsl:stylesheet> element.

Comment: You still did not answer this question: "Also, say whether you xsl:include or xsl:import the "other" stylesheets." Do you get an error if you use this variable in the main stylesheet only?

Comment: I would encourage you to edit your question with more information along the lines of the questions @MathiasMüller is asking. Without more information we can't really help you.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the IDE. Any variable declared as a child of the root element in a stylesheet should be usable anywhere in any imported/included stylesheets, and the `namespace` attribute of an `xsl:element` declaration can accept an attribute value template like this. You could try disabling the XSL validator; instructions here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/enable-disable-validators-rational-application-developer/

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT, when module A includes module B, module B is allowed to contain references to variables declared in A. However, because module B contains no reference to module A, it's difficult for an IDE to know that a variable declaration exists. oXygen solves this by allowing you to declare the dependency, but I have no idea if RAD has a similar capability. If it doesn't, you should be able to ignore the spurious error.